# How can I access the "more from this user" playlist in the new YouTube design?

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist

YouTube used to have a "more from" dropdown box on every video, from which you could easily pick the next/previous video from a user's uploads. I watch lots of sequential content from users with large numbers of videos, so this was great. Even better, clicking a video from the list automatically put you into an auto-generated playlist that would play each of the user's videos in order, which made sequential content much easier to consume.

The "More From" dropdown is gone now, and there seem to be no way to get to that auto-playlist anymore. The URL slug to access it still works though, as I had a YouTube window open with a playlist URL slug right when YouTube did the change. The playlists still work, I just can't seem to find any way to actually get to the playlist without already having the playlist open.

How can I open the "more from X" playlist in YouTube now?

Answer (score 1):

The playlist is available in the current design (One Channel, which you're referring to as "new design") if the user has featured a "newest video" shelf on their channel page – click the "play all" button.

In the now-new design (Material Design), there is a link to play all videos on the /videos tab of any channel.